# Spring Web Flow: Can't get second view

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am using Spring Web Flow to a registration process. I have the first page of the flow perfectly, but when I click on the button that should take you to page two, I get again the first page of the flow. As you will see in the code, I have flowExecutionKey on a label, and it goes from e1s1 to e2s1 when I click on the button, so instead of leading me to the second view of the flow, it starts a new flow, I think.

Here is the code:

So, I have this flow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd" start-state="inicio">
    <var name="proyecto" class="myPackage.MyModelClass"/>
<view-state id="inicio" view="inicio" model="proyecto">
    <binder>
        <binding property="titulo"/>
        <binding property="descripcion"/>
        <binding property="ciudad"/>

    </binder>
    <transition on="gotoPageTwo" to="flow2"></transition>

</view-state>
<view-state id="flow2" view="flow2" model="proyecto">
    <transition on="gotoPageThree" to="flow3"></transition>
    <transition on="goBack" to="inicio"></transition>
</view-state>
<view-state id="flow3" view="flow3" model="proyecto">
    <transition on="gotoPageFour" to="fin"></transition>
    <transition on="goBack" to="flow2"></transition>
</view-state>
<end-state id="fin" view="final">
</end-state>
```

This is my inicio.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="/myapp/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/myapp/resources/css/tcal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/resources/scripts/tcal.js"></script>
<title>Paso 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="inicio.do">
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}">
<label>flowExecutionKey: ${flowExecutionKey}</label>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="textform">Título del proyecto</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="titulo">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="textform">Descripción</label>
        </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="descripcion">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="textform">Ciudad del proyecto</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="ciudad">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Siguiente" name="_eventId=gotoPageTwo">
    <%--<a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=gotoPageTwo&_flowExecutionKey=${flowExecutionKey}"> Siguiente página</a> 
         <input type="submit" value="Siguiente" name="eventId=gotoPageTwo">
          <input type="submit" value="Siguiente" name="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=gotoPageTwo">--%>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, i try to send an eventId of gotoPageTwo, as is stated in flow.xml.

And Spring web Flow related beans on servlet-context.xml:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">

    <beans:property name="mappings">
    <beans:value>inicio.do=flowController</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="flowcontroller" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
<beans:property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices"> 
        <webflow:flow-location id="inicio" path="/WEB-INF/flujos/flow.xml"/> 
</webflow:flow-registry>   
<webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" 
        view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator"/>
        <beans:bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
        <beans:property name="viewResolvers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="viewResolver"/>
        </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

Why is this happening? Where is my error? The first link in the comments works and presents the second view, but it does not send the form, I think, so I have no data, and its a link, not a button:

```
<a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=gotoPageTwo&_flowExecutionKey=${flowExecutionKey}"> Siguiente página</a>
```

The other comments are things I tried, and doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the code to:

```
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Siguiente" name="_eventId_gotoPageTwo">
    </td>
```

When you are using anchor href, you are passing _eventId as a parameter and so you have it _eventId=gotoPageTwo

whereas now the "_eventId" is encoded in the name of a button field and so when the form is submitted, the "gotoPageTwo" event will be signaled in the current state of the flow.

Also, change form to

```
    <form:form method="post"  modelAttribute="proyecto">
```

Comment: That was a nice tip, i was confusing = with _ in the name of the button, but however, unfortunately it does not work. I keep having the first state of the flow, with the flowexecutionKey changing from e1s1 to e2s1. Thanks.

Comment: 2 questions in context file: 1)Why do you have 2 flowControllers? 2)How is viewResolver bean?(show the details)

Comment: 1) I have been doing lots of testing, maybe I added the last one without realisin I had added one previously 2) See edit.

Comment: Ok, action attribute in not to be used as view is flowController controlled. Also, I would suggest using spring form tags. I made an edit to suggest the same in answer. Remove the multiple flowController definitions.

Comment: I moved to the Spring Form Library, and now it works. Thank you! But does this means I cannot do it without using this tag library?

Comment: You can avoid the Spring form and use an HTML form, if you don't want to have a bean storing some values for the form.